# Setting WiFi on Linux platforms using wpa_supplicant vs connmanctl?

Tags: linux, wpa, connman

I have observed some linux distribution have 
`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` which can be configured to setup WiFi.

On the other hand some distributions have connmanctl `utility/tool`.
Where we have `/var/lib/connman/<SSID>-psk.config` file.

Can someone explain the difference between these two and who exactly uses these files to make wifi work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`connman`** is a network configuration tool such as `wicd`, `netctl` or `NetworkManager`.

**`wpasupplicant`** is a [supplicant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplicant_(computer)) that allows wpa authentication (and more) **even with `connmanctl`**.